# How to configure TFS 2012 to use vstest.console.exe

Tags: mstest

We use TFS 2012
Through a build definition we execute automated tests from MTM test plans.
How can we ensure TFS uses vstest.console.exe to run each test?
I've read online from other posts that TFS 2012 let's you choose either MSTest or VSTest as the test runner.
I've also read that if you use MTM you effectively are locked into using a test settings file(.testsettings) which means you are locked into using MSTest.  This seems to go against TFS 2012 giving you a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test Manager currently is only supporting MsTest. This is a limitation in Test Manager. It's the same issue that prevents you from associating a xUnit or NUnit test automation on a test case.

So while TFS 2012 gives you the choice, each choice comes with its own set of limitations.

To be clear:

- New test runner: Work in Continuous Integration, you specify which tests to run by selecting the new agile test runner (in TFS 2013 this is a fixed choice in the default templates, template customization is required to run mstest). It can run tests during build and you can directly invoke it from the commandline if you want to run tests after deployment. You can use a [`.runsettings` file to specify certain options it should pick up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx). This option is required to execute 3rd party test frameworks like NUnit, XUnit.NET, Chutzpah etc.
- The MTM test runner: Execute automated tests that are associated to a Test Case work item or execute tests using the Test Agent to run tests from a remote system using the Team Test infrastructure. [You can use a `.testsettings` file to specify certain options it should pick up.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231892.aspx) These tests will be executed using MsTest and cannot contain 3rd party test frameworks.

In your Continuous Integration build you can configure multiple Test Runs, each can be configured to a specific test framework. So you can have both options in your build.

[More on the differences and how you can use the different settings files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991.aspx).

Over time all test options will be moved to the new test runner. In TFS 2013 the option to configure a MsTest based test run in your Build Definition has been removed by default. You will need to customize the build process to select a different test runner.

Comment: Do you mean that if you're using TFS 2012, you won't be able to run tests that require vstest.console (like Windows Phone 8 tests) in a continuous integration environment ?

Comment: TFS 2012 CI builds will happily execute both types of tests. Limitations are around using Test manager or the Test Agent infrastructure to run tests.

Comment: Do you have skills in CI with Windows Phone unit tests projects ? Actually i can't get my build controller to execute WP8 unit tests ".xap" packages. It's silently skipping all of them. I succeed in test running them from the vstest.console.exe command line

Comment: You're right, just posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26252785/1303737)

Comment: Are you implying TFS 2013 will also run tests from Test Manager/MTM using vstest.console.exe and by default?

Comment: No. By default it will not run these tests at all. It will only run tests that can be executed by the new test runner. Unless you modify the default templates. The activity is still there.

Comment: Understood.  Do you happen to know an ETA on Test Manager supporting vstest.console.exe?  Release date, version, etc.  Even a rough forecast.  Thanks for all the insight by the way.

Comment: I'm hoping vNext, I suppose that would be TFS 2015? I know as much as you do.