# Running Windows Phone 8.0 tests in a Continuous Integration environment

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration

I have a VS 2013 solution with a WP8 App, a WP8 Library for my viewmodels, a WP8 Unit Test project to test my library and other standard unit tests projects. The solution is under TFS 2012 source control, the build controller is setup and it correctly build my solution.

But my WP8 specific tests are not ran after automatic build. All other standard Unit Tests projects run well.

Some additional infos:

- the ".xap" package for the test project is well generated
- the build process Template (Default Template) is setup to use "Visual Studio Test Runner"
- the build agent is running interactively
- when i launch vstest.console.exe from the command line, giving the ".xap" package as argument, the test are well discovered and executed

I'am i missing something in the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone apps are currently not supported on Team Build, [as documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn168930(v=vs.105).aspx).

```
Feature            | Windows Phone  | Windows Store App
Team Build support | Not supported. | Includes support for running unit tests as part of Team Build.
```

There are a few unsupported work-arounds to solve your issue, [more an be found here](https://gist.github.com/codito/e430d3b155b9af675ba9).

Comment: Sorry for mixing up the Windows Store app execution with the Windows Phone ones before.

Comment: As a side note, this workaround is only available with TFS 2013, as the TfvcTemplate is not available with TFS 2012

Comment: You can edit the 2012 template and drop in a InvokeProcess activity, passing in the required parameters.

Comment: Yes, that was my ultimate solution... but i must admit that workflows are not my cup of tea ^^ If i edit it, must I have to also edit the workflow to fetch the vstest.console test results in order to display them in Build report ?

Comment: Not sure. Since the logger is passed to the call as an argument, it might actually show up automatically.